# How does Haskell infer type during an instance declaration?

Tags: haskell

I have this data type and instance declaration:

```
class Expr a where
  lit :: Integer -> a

data Mod7 = Mod7 Integer deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Expr Mod7 where
  lit x = Mod7 (x `mod` 7)
```

This compiles just fine. I assume that's because this line

```
lit x = Mod7 (x `mod` 7)
```

infers that `x` is a type that can be passed to `mod`. How can this inference happen without some explicit declaration?

The definition of mod is

```
mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

So given the above declarations, its totally possible that `lit` wouldve been passed an `Integral` type that did not have a function declared. How did GHC know what type to assign to `x`?

Comment: "its totally possible that `lit` wouldve been passed an `Integral` type that did not have a function declared" - what do you mean? Which function might not have been declared on the type with a `Integral` instance?

Comment: Adding to Isaac's point about all `Integral`s having `mod`; note that `class Expr a where lit :: Integer -> a` specifies that `lit` takes an `Integer`, hence `x` is an `Integer`.

Answer (score 8):

Type inference in instance declarations works the same as in any other context. In this case there are two lines of reasoning that establish that `x` is an `Integer`.

1. `x` appears in the expression `` Mod7 (x `mod` 7) ``. Since the `Mod7` constructor is declared to take an `Integer` argument, `` x `mod` 7 `` must be an `Integer`. Since `mod` is of type `Integral a => a -> a -> a`, if the result of `` x `mod` 7 `` is an `Integer`, then both `x` and `7` must also be `Integer` (this only works if `Integral Integer` holds, but it does so that's fine).
2. `lit` has been declared to have type `Expr a => Integer -> a` (in the class definition for `Expr a`). `x` was bound as the argument in a definition of `lit`, so it must be of type `Integer`.

The only thing that's specific to instance declarations is that the type checker can instantiate the type of the functions declared in the class with the type(s) for this specific instance. So it actually knows that (because this is in `instance Expr Mod7`, that the `lit` definition is for `lit :: Integer -> Mod7`. However that wasn't even necessary to establish `x :: Integer`, since the argument type of `lit` is the same in every instance for `Expr` (this instance-specific knowledge is used to establish that calling the `Mod7` constructor is the correct way to build the return value, but isn't relevant to inferring the type of `x`).